# Storing energy from small wind generator to power led garden lights

Tags: electrical, generator, battery, wind

I want to create a small wind generator using a bike generator (se picture) to power some led garden lights during the night.

I have so far created a 1m in diamater wood propeller and a rotating house for the generator that seem to work well (the propeller rotates and the housing turns to face the wind).

My current problem is energy storage. The generator creates somewhere between 10-13 Volts on a decent day. The led lights in the garden will be either 6 or 12v (I havent bought them yet). I have two questions.

1. What kind of battery is suitable for this type of things (continous
   slow charge and discharge, I'm thinking a car battery, but I don't know).
2. Can anyone link to some type of battery management electronic that will keep the battery from getting fried by over/under charging?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: use a solar charge controller to manage the battery. all around, nicd is probably the best bet: little memory effect and a wide temp range. a few 18650 lions would also work, and it's easy to get charge controllers for them. avoid SLA since this is outside: it gets too cold for them to work, and you will likely wear out wet chemistry in a year or less...

Answer (score 1):

A deep cycle battery is what you want. A standard car battery really is not designed to charge and discharge where a deep cycle is made to do that so it will have a longer usable life.